# Как подставить категорию к кнопке?

Tags: html, dle

Как добавить категорию к кнопке, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку переходить на категорию, а не по ссылке?

P.S. у меня cms DLE

Comment: @v1ados, DLE - это довольно - таки **убогая** CMS, перейдите на WordPress, проблем (а судя по вашим вопросам у Вас их не мало) станет гораздо меньше

Answer (score 1):

А в вашу CMS нельзя ли вставить код html для элемента вручную?:

```
<input type="button" value="Категория" onclick="location.href='новый адрес'">
```

это код кнопки которая осуществляет переход на `новый адрес`